# Meteor 0.9 : Use helpers to return Template with data?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

In helper function, i want to return template with data based on some conditions like this :

```
if(this.notificationType == 'QUESTION') {
var question = Question.findOne(this.objectId);
//I want to to pass the data here !
return Tempalte.displayQuestion
}

if(this.notificationType == 'ANSWER') {
var answer= ANSWERS.findOne(this.objectId);
//I want to to pass the answer data here !
return Tempalte.displayAnswer
}
```

How is it possible to do such thing ?
thx!

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#blaze_tohtmlwithdata